# Is passing activity_regularizer as argument to Conv2D() the same as passing it seperately right after Conv2D()? (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, regularized

I was wondering whether creating the model by passing `activity_regularizer='l1_l2'` as an argument to Conv2D()

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(6, 6), strides=3, padding='valid', activation='relu',
                   activity_regularizer='l1_l2', input_shape=X_train[0].shape))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 1), strides=3, padding='valid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.001), loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 10, validation_data = (X_val, y_val), verbose=0)
```

will mathematically make a difference to creating the model by adding `model.add(ActivityRegularization(l1=..., l2=...))` seperately?

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(6, 6), strides=3, padding='valid', activation='relu',
                   input_shape=X_train[0].shape))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(ActivityRegularization(l1=some_number, l2=some_number))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 1), strides=3, padding='valid')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.001), loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 10, validation_data = (X_val, y_val), verbose=0)
```

For me, it is hard to tell, as training always involves some randomness. But the results seem similar.

One additional question I have is: I accidentally passed the `activity_regularizer='l1_l2'` argument to the MaxPooling2D() layer before, and the code ran. How can that be, considering that `activity_regularizer` is not given as a possible argument for MaxPooling2D() in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, if you are not applying any other constraint on the layer output, applying the activity regularizer inside the layer as well as outside the convolution layer is same. However, applying it outside the convolution layer gives the user more flexibility. For instance, the user might want to regularize the output units after the skip connections are set up instead of after the convolution. It is just like to have an activation function inside the convolution layer or using `keras.activations` to use the activations after he convolution layer. Sometimes this is done after batch normalization.

For your second question, the `MaxPool2D` layer takes the activity regularizer constraint. Even though this is not mentioned in their documentation, it kind of makes sense intuitionally, since the user might want to regularize the outputs after max-pooling. You can check that `activity_regularizer` does not only work with the `MaxPool2D` layer but also with other layers such as the `BatchNormalization` layer for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "after the skip connections are set up"?

Comment: This means that some user might want to use the activity regularizer not right after the convolution but after the skip/residual connections (taht use identity mapping). You can read about skip connections here: https://theaisummer.com/skip-connections/.

Answer (score 1):

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64 , 2 , padding='same', activity_regularizer='l1_l2')
```

and this code,

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64 , 2 , padding='same')
tf.keras.layers.ActivityRegularization()
```

They both do the same job, actually doing inside or outside has the same impact. Moreover, Tensorflow on the backend makes a graph of it which will first apply the ConvLayer then it will apply the Activity-Regularization, in both cases, the computation shall be done in the same way with no difference...